# Sharedpreferences makes the app stop working

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have a code that works fine in android studio emulator but when I run it on real device it stops working.

Please guide me, thank you.

Here is the part of my code:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

  public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
  public static final String Mobile = "mobileNum";
  public static final String ActivationCode = "activationCode";
  public static final String SecurityCode = "securityCode";

  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String mobileNumber = sharedpreferences.getString(Mobile, null);
    String activationCode = sharedpreferences.getString(ActivationCode, null);
    String securityCode = sharedpreferences.getString(SecurityCode, nu

    activationCode = random();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(ActivationCode, activationCode);
    editor.commit();
  }
}
```

Note that if i disable this codes it will have no error.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(ActivationCode, activationCode);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Where is "MyPREFERENCES"?

Comment: Yeah, should maybe include the stacktrace..

Comment: what does the function random() return ?

Comment: MyPREFERENCES is defined with a name.

Comment: random , returns a random string with 6 characters

Comment: Make sure `random()` returns a valid String, not int or sth.

Comment: Ugurcan Yildirim  , MyPREFERENCES doesnt need to be defined with a pre default values ? i am just reading it and it has no values ! i dont know how to check it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apply instead of commit. commit is blocking.